# Kotlin wait for function to finish then complete code

Tags: android, kotlin

In my code, I have 2 functions that update global variables. When I call them (On top of onCreate)

Like this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    userManager = UserManager(this) 
        observeEmail()
        observePassword()
```

Code continues, I want to wait for these 2 functions to finish then to continue my code how can I do that?

As you can see first is printed message from onCreate, then from the function which is before print in onCreate

[prints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMW3u.png)

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKJdD.png)

Comment: Functions return immediately if they aren’t suspend functions in a coroutine. Do you mean you are observing LiveDatas and want to wait for both of them to emit at least one result before doing something else?

Comment: I added the function in question, the function is taking data from DataStore and I think it takes time, when I print something in the function it is printed after the print in the OnCreate function. i will also add screenshots

Comment: If you do so, you'll be blocking the UI thread until they finish. You need a coroutine or a background thread to run these functions on and return their results to the UI when they are over.

Comment: It will not be a problem if it blocks the UI thread for that amount of time. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like the second param in that observe() method is a callback.

My suggestion is this:

Way way up at the very top of the class, create a class-global variable called callBack like this:

```
callBack:(()->Unit)?=null
```

Then, inside of your onCreate() push everything that you want to happen after observeEmail into one massive routine and let callBack take the value of that routine. Like this:

```
callBack={doEverything()
doMore()
doOtherStuff()
}
```

Now go back inside that second param of .observe(), you know that place where you printed the email hint. And under that print line, add this:

```
callBack?.invoke()
```

Now everything will wait until observe() returns a result.

Comment: And for people reading this and reflexively saying "NO; Don't hang the UI thread!", I say just let them feel out the logic of using a callback, and once they have a prototype working, they'll be able to fine-tune for themselves what needs to await and what can be totally async.

Comment: Why would this cause a hang? It’s just a callback. But anyway, we don’t know if the password or the email will be emitted first, or how many times. They need to be merged with a mediator or some extra properties need to be added to track both observed values and determine from either observer whether to run the callback.

Comment: Well the question referenced the email method specifically, so I'm just going off of that and they can extrapolate. They might end up putting the password method inside the callback and then the god callback I suggested inside the password callback. 

As far as whether it will cause hang, it should because the stuff that will end up going inside my suggested god callback will most likely handle a bunch of ui stuff. And if the OP uses it like they had originally asked, they'll end up putting the super call in there, which should cause some hang.